# What can be achieved via a partial Euler formula

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

It is well-known that
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$
I was curious about the following question: If we, instead of summing over all $n\in\mathbf N$, sum over an infinite proper subset of $\mathbf N$ on the RHS of the Euler formula, what type of function can we obtain? For example, what are
$$\sum_{n\equiv 0\,(\text{mod}\,2)}\frac{x^n}{n!},\,\,\,\,\sum_{n\text{ is squared} }\frac{x^n}{n!},\,\,\,\,\sum_{n\text{ is prime}}\frac{x^n}{n!}\,\,?$$
Or can we at least have an estimate on the speed of divergence for cases alike? Are there any known results on this?

Comment: Well, the first one is $\cosh(x)$. I doubt there are closed forms for the other ones though.

Comment: @VarunVejalla Yeah, but can we obtain a function by properly choosing the subset so that the speed of its divergence is strictly lower than $e^x$, but not too much lower, that is, the ratio diverges like a polynomial?

Comment: Why divergence ? The sum converges whatever subset of $\mathbb N$ we use and whatever $x$ is.

Comment: @Peter Sorry for the confusion... by divergence I meant that when $x\to\infty$.